# List returns null when passing from view to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an `ActionResult` in my `Controller` which retrieves data from the database using stored procedure.

**RIROController.cs**:

```
public ActionResult myRIRO()
{
    // Calls the main ViewModel
    var vm = new ResourceViewModel();

    string EID = Session["EID"].ToString();


    vm.CheckValues = db_RIRO.sp_GetAllCheckStatus()
    .Select(a => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = a.CheckID.ToString(),
        Text = a.CheckStatus
    })
    .ToList();

    // Calls the dictionary RIROList is nested inside ResourceViewModel 
    vm.UserRIList = new List<RIROFormViewModel>();
            // Set current user's value of completion status to ddl
    sp_GetUserRIForm_Result RIUserChkValue = db_RIRO.sp_GetUserRIForm(EID).FirstOrDefault();
    sp_GetUserROForm_Result ROUserChkValue = db_RIRO.sp_GetUserROForm(EID).FirstOrDefault();

    vm.RICheckID = RIUserChkValue.CheckID;
    vm.ROCheckID = ROUserChkValue.CheckID;

    foreach (var item in db_RIRO.sp_GetUserRIForm(Session["EID"].ToString()))
    {
        vm.UserRIList.Add(new RIROFormViewModel()
        {
            ItemNo = item.ItemNo,
            CheckItem = item.CheckItem,
            EmployeeTypeID = item.EmployeeTypeID,
            ItemID = item.ItemID,
            CheckID = item.CheckID,
            DateCompleted = item.DateCompleted,
            RIComment = item.Comments

        });
    }
   return View(vm);
}
```

**View/myRIRO.cshtml**

```
@model OnlineRIRO.ViewModel.ResourceViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateRIROForm", "RIRO", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @foreach (var item in Model.UserRIList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ItemNo</td>
            <td>@Html.Raw(item.CheckItem)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.RICheckID, Model.CheckValues, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a => item.RIComment, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the data inside the `vm.UserRIList` and execute a stored procedure on each item in that collection.

**UpdateRIROForm**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateRIROForm(ResourceViewModel riroInfo)
{
    var EID = Session["EID"].ToString();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in riroInfo.UserRIList)
            {
              db_RIRO.sp_UpdateUserRIRODraft(EID, item.ItemID, item.CheckID, item.RIComment)
              db_RIRO.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("myRIRO");
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("myRIRO");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Fail"] = 1;
        return RedirectToAction("myRIRO");
    }

}
```

When I debugged the `UpdateRIROForm` the `riroInfo.UserRIList` is null. Is there anything missing in my code?

Comment: Use a for loop with indexing in the View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop with indexing in the View

```
@model OnlineRIRO.ViewModel.ResourceViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateRIROForm", "RIRO", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" })) {
    @for(int index = 0, index < Model.UserRIList.Count, index++) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.UserRIList[index].ItemNo</td>
            <td>@Html.Raw(Model.UserRIList[index].CheckItem)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RICheckID, Model.CheckValues, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserRIList[index].RIComment, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

this will allow the collection in the model to be populated when the form is posted back to the controller.

Comment: Thanks! It's now working. Why do I need to declare an index? Doesn't C# automatically place all the data in a list?

Comment: @Odie The framework needs to be able to interpret the data submitted by the form the index helps organize which data belongs to with record in the collection. On the client side it is not a referenced type you are dealing but HTML. When form is submitted, the framework takes the data and constructs the models based on the submitted data

Comment: I noticed that the code removed the default selected value for my dropdownlist is there any solution on this? :)

Comment: @Odie is the `RICheckID` part of the item or the model?

Comment: It's a part of the model. Added the code on where I used to get the default value.

Comment: it returns an error saying that its an int. i tried adding a `ToString()` which shows the correct ID but it only adds to the list of the dropdownlist.